# My Car Stalled Out And I'm Getting A New One - How Do I Trade It In?

Tags: stall, towing, selling

My car recently stalled out on me, and has since only been able to drive up to 20 minutes before stalling out again.

To bypass a lot of questions about fixing the stall, I'm not planning to do that - I've taken it to a garage and they've told me getting it fixed would require going to a dealership, and having researched the cost of repair versus trading it in as-is, the difference just isn't worth it to me.

So now I want to trade it in to a dealer, but how do I get the car *to* the dealer to trade it in?  Will dealers tow the car in for me?  Do I need to get an independent tow organization to do it? Or is it unlikely that a dealer will even take my car for any amount?

Comment: It depends on your location and the year, make and model of the car you want to trade.  That being said, it's doubtful you'll get enough for the car to cover the towing cost unless it's a high-end vehicle.